# How can I migrate user profile content?

Tags: 6, users, migrations

I am using `user_save()` to migrate users from another application into Drupal, but my profile fields are not updating.

Does anyone have any suggestions as why this isn't working, or how I can get it to

```
        $newUser = array(
          'name' => $row->user_name,  
          'pass' => $row->user_password, // note: do not md5 the password   
          'mail' => $row->user_email,    
          'status' => 1,    

          'profile_title'=>$row->user_title,
          'profile_firstname'=>$row->user_first_name,
          'profile_lastname'=>$row->user_last_name,
          'profile_jobtitle'=>$row->user_job_title,
          'profile_orgname'=>$row->user_organization,
          'profile_telno'=>$row->user_contact_no,
          'profile_faxno'=>$row->user_fax_no,
          'profile_streetaddress'=>$row->user_address1.$row->user_address2,
          //'profile_address2'=>sanjay,
          'profile_city'=>$row->user_city,
          //'profile_state'=>sanjay,
          'profile_postalcode'=>$row->user_postal_code,
          'profile_country'=>$row->iso,
          //'profile_stateprovince'=>$row->sanjay,
          //'old_user_id'=> $row->user_id,
          'init' =>$row->user_initial,
        );     
        user_save(null,$newUser);
```

Comment: which version of drupal you're using? how these user fields were created in drupal? can you show us a sample of your code?

Comment: i am using drupal 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [User import](http://drupal.org/project/user_import) module can help you with that

Comment: no it don't its only for import not for migration.

Comment: yeah, but you can export a csv file from the old website and import it in drupal

Comment: i tried in this way also...

Comment: I usually do it this way: implement hook_user and print_r the $edit or $account object when inserting a new user from the interface. That way you'll see the exact structure of the user object and can construct your $newUser object based on that one.